# Estrutura condicional if else não estão funcionando

Tags: javascript

Estou com a seguinte situação: Tenho um formulário com alguns selects e 2 inputs. Um com data início que será preenchido pelo usuário que é do type date e outro com o type text. Conforme imagem abaixo:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" onchange="getRadioSelected1()">
                            5 dias
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" onchange="getRadioSelected2()">
                            10 dias
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3" onchange="getRadioSelected3()">
                            15 dias
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4" onchange="getRadioSelected4()">
                            20 dias
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios5" value="option5" onchange="getRadioSelected5()">
                            30 dias
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios6" value="option6" onchange="getRadioSelected6()">
                            5 dias com a venda de 10 dias
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios7" value="option7" onchange="getRadioSelected7()">
                            15 dias com a venda de 10 dias
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="bloqueio_campo" id="optionsRadios8" value="option8" onchange="getRadioSelected8()">
                            20 dias com a venda de 10 dias
                            </label>
                        </div><br>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="dt_inicio">Data início das Férias</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dt_inicio" id="dt_inicio" onchange='pegaDtInicial()'>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="dt_fim">Data fim das Férias</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dt_fim" id="dt_fim" readonly>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

ao clicar na data início devo verificar qual dos radios foi escolhido e preencher o input da data fim com este valor.

para adquirir o valor do input eu fiz:

function dtFinal(data){

```
 if(getRadioSelected1){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value = 'Radio 1 Selecionado';
 }else if(getRadioSelected2){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value =  'Radio 2 Selecionado';
 }else if(getRadioSelected3){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value =  'Radio 3 Selecionado';
 }else if(getRadioSelected4){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value =  'Radio 4 Selecionado';
 }else if(getRadioSelected5){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value =  'Radio 5 Selecionado';
 }else if(getRadioSelected5){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value =  'Radio 6 Selecionado'o;
 }else if(getRadioSelected6){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value =  'Radio 7 Selecionado'';
 }else if(getRadioSelected7){
     document.getElementById("dt_fim").value =  'Radio 8 Selecionado';
 }else{
     console.log('Valor inválido!');

 }
```

}

Só que o problema é que por algum motivo ao clicar em qualquer um dos radios, ele só preenche o input dt fim com o valor Radio 1 Selecionado. Ele não está entrando nos outros ifs. Por favor, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Erika, não tem como dar uma resposta que resolva o seu problema. Estão faltando informações. Deixando claro: quando faz `if(getRadioSelected1)` o termo `getRadioSelected1` é uma função que demanda um parâmetro. No caso você está testando se a expressão `getRadioSelected1` referencia algo ou é nulo e como `getRadioSelected1` é a referencia para função declarada `function getRadioSelected1(valor)` o mesmo é válido para todas as outras funções.

Comment: Por que não dá para dar uma resposta precisa? Porque todas as funções no seu código definidas coma a assinatura `getRadioSelectedXXX(valor)` demandam um parâmetro `valor` e tanto a função `function pegaDtInicial(data)` e restante do código apresentado não fornecem informações suficientes para inferir sobre a origem do valor passado para as funções `getRadioSelectedXXX(valor)` testadas nas função `function pegaDtInicial(data)`.

Comment: Trocando em miúdos, teria que ser feito algo assim em todos os seus if's `if(getRadioSelected1( ??? ))` mas não temos como saber o que vai onde está escrito`???`.

Comment: Outra coisa: dentro de cada função `getRadioSelectedXXX(valor)` a forma como faz suas comparações estão equivocadas. Quando faz `if(valor = 'option1')` você não está comparando expressões, na verdade você está  atribuindo `'option1'` a `valor` quando quiser fazer comparações em javascript use o comparador `==` para saber apenas se os conteúdos são iguais e o comparador `===` para saber se os conteúdos e tipos são iguais.

Comment: Obrigada Augusto, você tem razão, não estou sendo muito clara com o meu objetivo, por esse motivo, vou reescreve-lo novamente:

Comment: Faça isso pois a pergunta está juntando varias respostas sem sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não consigo entender exatamente o que você quis fazer dentro da função `pegaDtInicial`, porém ao verifica dentro de um `if` a função `getRadioSelected1` você não está verificando um valor e sim se ela possui uma referência ou não.

Se você quiser comparar o valor de retorno da função, você deve chamá-la primeiro (como sua função possui um parâmetro, você deve passar algum valor na chamada). Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function func(){
    return 2;
}

func == 2 // false
func() == 2 // true
```

Porém no seu código, mesmo chamando a função você nunca entraria no bloco `if` já que na função `getRadioSelected1` você não declara nenhum retorno. Sendo assim, por padrão a sua função retorna `undefined` que é equivalente a `null` ou `false`.

---

Há também um grave problema no seu código que é ao verifica se o valor é igual a string `option<n>`. Nas condicionais `if`, você está utilizando um [operador de atribuição](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) ao invés de um operador de comparação.

Para corrigir o problema basta você trocar o operador `=` pelo operador `==`, dessa forma:

```
if(valor == 'option'){
    //...
}
```

Além desse operador, há também um outro operador de comparação que você pode utilizar que é o `===`. Esse operador irá comparar não só o valor, como também o tipo do dado: Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
'1' == 1 // true
'1' === 1 // false (apesar do valor ser o mesmo, o tipo é diferente)
```

Comment: Jean, o código dela não chega nem a chamar essas comparações. Na verdade ele não entra em nenhuma das funções `getRadioSelectedXXX(valor)`, todas as respostas a essa pergunta estão equivocadas.

Comment: Eu percebi, estou editando editando a minha resposta agora.

Comment: Leia os comentários que fiz na pergunta, para ver se ajuda. Mas acho que não tem salvação, pois faltam informações. Mas qualquer coisa me marca quando der a resposta.

Comment: Ok, eu já reescrevi a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está em todas as condições e chamada de função, pois ao invés de comparar um valor com outro vocês está atribuindo o valor a ele, já em suas chamadas de função, não está sendo passado nenhum parâmetro e suas funções estão esperando receber um valor.

#### 1º Problema - Condição if:

`valor = 'option2'`, isso significa que você atribuiu `option2` para a variável `valor`.

O certo seria `valor == 'option2'`

Deve trocar `=` por `==`

---

#### 2º Problema - Chamada de função:

Dentro da função `pegaDtInicial`, existe algumas outras condições nessas condições as funções passada para dentro da condição estão incorretas, o certo seria alterar `if(getRadioSelected1)` por `if(getRadioSelected1(valor))`

Comment: Entendi! Vou fazer essas alterações. Muito obrigada pela dica.

Comment: Não é só esse o problema com o código. Leia os comentários anexados a pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

Isso é porque você está apenas atribuindo um valor e não comparando.

`=` É para fazer atribuições.

`==` Se for igual.

Então, você deve usar o `==` para fazer a comparação no seu condicional.

Comment: Ricardo, leia os comentários anexados a pergunta. Esse não é o único problema apresentado.